# including file handler in umbraco from vs2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, umbraco

Is there any possibilities to include file handler(.ashx) and aspx pages from visual studio 2005 to umbraco?if any one knows please reply.

Comment: Have you tried to yet?  What have you tried to do / what issues have you ran into?

Answer (score 0):

For the file handler, you shouldn't have any issues, just copy your ashx file and any code behind and dll files from your old project to the new project, you may also have to add a reference in your web config.

for the aspx file, you may run into issues with umbraco's URL rewriter, depending on what is on your page, you may have to
- create a new doc type, a new document and a new template in umbraco
- create a new template and use it with existing doc types in umbraco